# Difference Between scanner.nextLine() and scanner.nextInt()

Tags: loops, java.util.scanner

### The challenge details:

In this challenge, you'll read 5 valid numbers from the console, entered by the user,
and print the sum of those ten numbers. You'll want to check that the numbers entered, are valid integers. If not, print out the message "Invalid number" to the console, but continue looping, until you do have 5 valid numbers.
Before the user enters each number, prompt them with the message, "Enter number #x:", Where x represents the count, 1, 2, 3, etc. And as an example there, the first message would look something like, "Enter number #1:", the next, "Enter number #2:", and so on.

---

### Code Block#01: Which works absolutely fine and iteratively asks me for a valid integer number as input

```
public static void readUserInput(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    while(i<=5){
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter number # "+i +": ");
            String number = scanner.nextLine();
            int numberInt = Integer.parseInt(number);
            i++;
            sum+=numberInt;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Number");
        }
    }

}
```

---

### Code Block#02: Which gets stuck in an infinite loop printing 'Enter number # 1' and 'Invalid Number' not allowing me to enter any number

```
public static void readUserInput(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    while(i<=5){
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter number # "+i +": ");
            Int numberInt = scanner.nextInt();
            i++;
            sum+=numberInt;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Number");
        }
    }

}
```

Wanted to understand the difference between scanner.nextLine() and scanner.nextInt() in this case.
Why 1 is working fine and the other isn't.

Comment: Once `nextInt` fails, the scanner never gets past that "bad" integer, and so will fail each time you try to read one.  Since `nextLine` did not fail, even if the string read wasn't a valid integer, it can continue reading new input successfully.